# Android WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw() method throws error

Tags: android, webview

For Api 21+ following method must be accepted
But when I write below method in my eclipse project
WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
it throws error 'The method enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw() is undefined for the type webview'

However, it works in my other projects very well. I tried checking for dependance of library but nothing worked
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution
Go to project properties and set project build target to higher